# Kafka Partitions Reassignment Performance Impact

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a Kafka production cluster with 5 nodes and about 500 topics. I need to expand my cluster to add 2 new nodes and since, Kafka does not provide automatic data repartitioning, I am looking to run `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` shipped along with Kafka distribution to rebalance all my topics in the overall 7 nodes in the cluster now.

Since I already have a large amount of production data in my cluster,

1. Will running this script block any concurrent writes to my Kafka topics ?
2. Will running this script slow down my cluster/producers/consumers ?
3. How can I stop this script while it is in-progress in case my cluster starts misbehaving during this script's execution ?

I am currently using Kafka `v0.8.2.0` with multiple producers and multiple consumers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What Kafka-reassign-partitions does is:

1. Create new replicas on the new brokers as needed
2. Have them replicate data until they catch up to the leader
3. Trigger leader elections where needed
4. Delete replicas where needed

The leader election phase will delay writes (like any leader failover).
Consumers / producers may slow down because the extra replication takes disk and network resources (sometimes significant resources)
You can't stop this while in progress. I mean, you can delete the relevant node from ZK, but it wasn't really tested and the new replicas created will stick around... I wouldn't try. If you are concerned, I recommend moving a partition at a time.

In 0.10.1.0 (now going to feature freeze), we'll add the capability to throttle the re-assignment work, which will limit the performance impact on producers and consumers.

Comment: how do you determine how much to throttle the reassignment?

Comment: Thats a tough one. I usually work with my network team to determine how much bandwidth is available and I know how much data I'll move, and sometimes I know how long I need it to take... so you find a number that works with these constraints.

Comment: @GwenShapira what if I am running a cluster with no replication (I don't care much about the loss of data). If I have a topic with 100 partitions running on 3 brokers and I added 1 more broker. What will happen here? since there are no replicas to be created on the new broker, how will the partition be moved to new broker? Thanks

Comment: @vishnuviswanath you need to run kafka-reassign-partitions.sh script to reassign partitions across kafka brokers

Comment: @VijayKansal thanks. My question was how will the data be copied to new nodes. In your original question, a new replica is created and data is moved to new replica. (this doesn't have any performance impact). In my example, since I don't have any replica, wondering how the 4 steps mentioned by Gwen will work? (since all those steps are based on replicas and no broker is every a follower).

Comment: It would still work for you.
Your are running with a replication factor of 1. While running kafka-reassign-partitions.sh you can either specify which brokers should be the replica nodes of topic-partition, or you can make the script itself decide random brokers for your topic-partition. This ways, new replicas would be created on new brokers with data replicated on them and caught up with current leader followed by a new leader election and finally, unnecessary replicas will be deleted.

Comment: @VijayKansal great. Thanks :)